ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in C# with Entity Framework (INSERT ALL with commit)
I try to read a SQL file during the Entity Framework update-database command:
public override void Up()
{
    this.SqlResource("Migrations.SqlMigrations.ImportData.sql");
}

Update-Database -SourceMigration 0 -StartUpProjectName Test

The reading works fine, but then I get the above error. I know there is some tricky behavior with the ; semicolon in C# and it doesn't work like in the Oracle SQL Developer.
Here is the code from my SQL file:
INSERT ALL 
INTO PLZ (PLZ_PK, PLZ, LOCATION, CREATION_DATE, CREATED_BY) 
VALUES ('1', '111111', 'Testcity1', to_timestamp('15.12.09 09:15:00,000000000'), 'Init Dateimport')
INTO PLZ (PLZ_PK, PLZ, LOCATION, CREATION_DATE, CREATED_BY) 
VALUES ('2', '222222', 'Testcity2', to_timestamp('15.12.09 09:15:00,000000000'), 'Init Dateimport')
...
..
.
SELECT * FROM dual
COMMIT

INSERT ALL 
INTO PLZ (PLZ_PK, PLZ, LOCATION, CREATION_DATE, CREATED_BY) 
VALUES ('3', '333333', 'Testcity3', to_timestamp('15.12.09 09:15:00,000000000'), 'Init Dateimport')
...
..
.
SELECT * FROM dual

The points (...) are not in the file, I just used them to represent that between the commit you have 500 rows. The splitting of the INSERT ALL statement with COMMIT works fine in Oracle SQL Developer and I don't get the error

PL/SQL: ORA-00913: Too many values

which usually occurs.

In Oracle, you can only use one statement in each command.

If your code is reading the SQL file and passing it in its entirety to Oracle in a single command then you will get a syntax error.
If your code is being passed to a pre-processor and that pre-processor will parse it and send individual statements to the database then you need to consult the documentation for that pre-processor - but the pre-processor will probably be looking for the statement terminators which are either ; or /.

Looking at this answer it appears that SqlResource just reads the file and passes the content to SqlOperation and that "Represents a provider specific SQL statement to be executed directly against the target database" so it is not pre-processing the statement in any way and is just passing it directly to the database. Therefore, Oracle's restrictions on a single statement-per-command (probably) apply.
You would need to either:

split it up into individual DML statements (which would not want the trailing semi-colons); or
wrap it in a PL/SQL block (which would want the trailing semi-colons for the SQL statement terminators but would not want the trailing slash for the PL/SQL statement terminator):

BEGIN
  INSERT ALL 
    INTO PLZ (PLZ_PK, PLZ, LOCATION, CREATION_DATE, CREATED_BY) 
    VALUES ('1', '111111', 'Testcity1', to_timestamp('15.12.09 09:15:00,000000000'), 'Init Dateimport')
    INTO PLZ (PLZ_PK, PLZ, LOCATION, CREATION_DATE, CREATED_BY) 
    VALUES ('2', '222222', 'Testcity2', to_timestamp('15.12.09 09:15:00,000000000'), 'Init Dateimport')
    -- ...
    -- ..
    -- .
    SELECT * FROM dual;

  INSERT ALL 
    INTO PLZ (PLZ_PK, PLZ, LOCATION, CREATION_DATE, CREATED_BY) 
    VALUES ('3', '333333', 'Testcity3', to_timestamp('15.12.09 09:15:00,000000000'), 'Init Dateimport')
    -- ...
    -- ..
    -- .
    SELECT * FROM dual;

  COMMIT;
END;

